Bool Tool Wont Work on Sculpted Object
I have a sculpture I want to cut holes in for a musical instrument, but the bool tool is failing to carve it out.
I've tried several tutorials, none are working, I reset the normals, in and out, also the faces, tried weld, not sure what else may work?

Here is a link to the file,


It's hard to say without seeing your blend file. I recommend to upload your file to blend-exchange.com and add the link to the initial question. *This service works for files under 30 MB. For bigger files you can use Google Drive

Did you try both the Fast and Exact options and try checking Self Intersecting and/or Hole Tolerant in the Solver Options section?

Yes, @JohnEason, I did all those steps, thanks for that advise. If either of you have the time, I would like to see if we can figure out why the holes wont cut the shell. Feel free to print the ocarina! You just have to cut the air duct box out and there's a blade to split the air on the other side, it has to be fused to the shell.

I am also having a little trouble fixing the union crease there, tried bridge loop edge fix and fixing the normals. Not much control over the sculpt still. Wish there was a function that would remove roughness.
